# Weird error with Go default servemux that magically vanishes

Tags: html, go, templates

I have come across a weird error when implementing Go's default servemux. The problem is this error persisted for a day and then suddenly disappeared with absolutely no change in the code. I wanted to practice by getting a simple login and register page going with templates.

I'm posting this here out of interest sake to see if someone way more intelligent can figure out why this might have happened.

Steps to reproduce:

1. run the go app "main.go"
2. go in a browser to http://localhost:8080/login  - login page loads fine.
3. Try http://localhost:8080/register - program panics and exits.

In the console I get this error:

```
2020/09/28 10:53:19 &{0xc00005eb40 0xc000232000 {} 0xed9c60 false false false false 0 {0 0} 0xc000210040 {0xc0002180e0 map[] false false} map[] false 0 -1 0 false false [] 0 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0] 0xc000216070 0} 500 template: no template "register.gohtml" associated with 
template "login.gohtml"
exit status 1
```

Here is my file structure:

```
Package
   -views
      -login.gohtml
      -register.gohtml
   -model
   -controllers
   -main.go
```

The templates are for now just a basic html boilerplate that say "this is login" and "this is register" respectively for testing purposes.

Here is the code in main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"
)

//Globals
var tpl *template.Template

//Parsing initial templates removes need to parse at response function.
func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("./views/*.gohtml"))
}

//Router
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", login)
    http.HandleFunc("/register/", register)
    http.HandleFunc("/login/", login)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

//Login page handler
func login(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "login.gohtml", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
    }
}

//Register page handler
func register(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "register.gohtml", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
    }
}
```

As I said for some reason it just started working again with no change to the code or nothing but time.

Comment: What does the panic say? Please include that in the question.

Comment: @Flimzy The only error output I get is from the log.Fatalln() which is this 2020/09/28 10:53:19 &{0xc00005eb40 0xc000232000 {} 0xed9c60 false false false false 0 {0 0} 0xc000210040 {0xc0002180e0 map[] false false} map[] false 0 -1 0 false false [] 0 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0] 0xc000216070 0} 500 template: no template "register.gohtml" associated with 
template "login.gohtml"
exit status 1

Comment: Your question says "program panics and exits". Are you saying that's not actually true?

Comment: If you're just saying it logs an error and exits, the error is pretty clear: There's no template called `register.gohtml`, which probably means that file does not exist on disk, or not at the expected location. Have you verified this?  Other than that, what makes you think the servemux is vanishing (what would that even mean?), or is in any way related to the problem?

Comment: Yeah I did verify that they do exist on the disk. register.gohtml is just a copy of login.gohtml and exist in the same directory. Made sure I saved them and could open them with another text editor. They definitely do exist.

Comment: @RudiVisagie when did you verify the files exist? Did you verify it before the error disappeared? Did you make sure that those files are there before you launched the program version that was failing? Adding files after you've launched the program would not fix the problem since you're parsing the ./views only once, at program launch. And how / where from did you launch the problematic version?

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, I created the files when I did my initial setup of the structure. They both existed before running the version with the error since I made them one after the other. I made sure that I ctrl  + s (saved). I did not add any other files afterward. If you look in the directory structure I launched the main.go app with "go run main.go" from directly in the directory using the console in vs code. It builds just fine and index works until you tried to go to register and then it threw the error and then poof works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [golang sources](https://golang.org/src/log/log.go#L202), `log.Fatal(ln|f)` will trigger `os.Exit(1)`.

I assume you have an issue with `register.gohtml`, try just to print the error to understand it, instead of failing with Fatal.

Comment: That's the thing. The only error output I can get is what I put in the question from when it was working. Then literally 0 changes to the code and just a day later running it again and it works so no error to print out now.

Comment: @RudiVisagie: Is your goal to fix the error, or just to understand why the program doesn't always exit?

Comment: I cant fix the error since it was there and then poof disappeared. My goal is to just try and see if someone would know how this could have happened with 0 changes to the code.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the template file did not exist at the time the error occurred, but did exist when the error did not occur.  But since we don't have access to the system, or a complete reproduction case, it's pretty hard to prove anything.

Comment: Yeah I thought that too but I can promise you both templates existed. I made them one after the other and saved them correctly.

Comment: Well, I can promise you that the error doesn't lie. There's a 99.9% chance the template doesn't exist at some point. The other 0.1% chance is beyond the ability of us to troubleshoot without access to your machine or a lot more information.